# How do I change the default hyphenated properties color in PowerShell console?

Tags: powershell, colors, console

Every argument that begins with "-" is a grey color. Is there a setting in Windows 10 to change the value of this color?

[image]

I typically don't use the default Blue background and some times it is simply not visible with other background colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this with `Set-PSReadlineOption`. E.g this would change it to red:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind parameter -ForegroundColor Red
```

You might also want to change it for operator and type as these are also Gray by default:

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind operator -ForegroundColor Red
Set-PSReadlineOption -TokenKind type -ForegroundColor Red
```

Answer (score 1):

The top-rated answer does not work as of 2021 and even at the time of the publication only worked for the immediate window. The more consistent solution is to get the PS profile path with:

```
echo $profile
```

and then add the following command to the file under the returned path:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{Operator = "Green"; Parameter = "Green"; Type = "DarkGreen"}
```

The profile.ps1 script launches every time PowerShell is executed, therefore keeping the color selection.